Are magnification and resolution dependent variable?
Doesn't magnification depend ONLY the lenses used? Does it depend on the wavelength as well? What makes an electron microscope magnify way bigger than its light counterpart? Is it because of the small wavelength in the electron microscope side or Is it because of ONLY the magnetic lenses used in there?

Magnification and resolution

Too many questions IMHO. Magnification does depend on wavelength. Expensive objectives try to compensate for it, but only to a certain extent. Electron microscopes are quite different. You could say that magnification there is better because the equivalent of wavelength in electrons is much shorter than in optics. You could get better magnification if you could use gamma-rays, but we don't have materials to make lenses for this type of light

TL;DR Transmission electron microscopes (TEMs) are not in a 4f configuration.
If I understand correctly, you are asking why a conventional light microscope hardly magnifies above 100X when electron microscopes easily achieve > 1 000 000X magnification. Most light microscopes are designed in the so-called 4f configuration. In short, the specimen is one objective focal length away from the objective lens, the tube lens is separated from the objective lens by the sum of their respective focal length, and the detector is at a focal distance of the tube lens. This configuration presents several advantages. Most notably, it allows the introduction of additional optical elements in the beam path with minimal impact on the system performance. This is of importance for fluorescence microscopy for example. However, in this configuration, the magnification is given by the ratio of the tube lens focal length over the objective lens focal length. The tube lens focal length is generally around 200mm for most commercial microscopes. This means a 100X objective lens would have a focal length of 2mm (in air). To produce a 1 000 000X magnification with a 2-mm focal length objective lens in a 4f configuration, one would have to use a tube lens of 2km. Quite impractical, and in fact not necessary, because the resolution of an optical system is anyway limited by diffraction. The diffraction limit for light microscopes is given by the Rayleigh criterion or roughly the wavelength divided by twice the numerical aperture (NA). If we assume a wavelength of 400nm and a good NA of 0.95, this is a diffraction limit of 400 / ( 2 * 0.95 ) = 210.5nm. A typical CMOS pixel is a square with a side length of about 4-7um. Take for example a pixel with a size of 4.5um. At 100X magnification, the same pixel appears with a size 4.5/100 = 0.045um or 45nm. This is already satisfying the sampling criterion. Although some might say it is better to go beyond the sampling criterion (but this is a whole other topic...). So, why is it that electron microscopes can achieve more than 1 000 000X? I am not an expert in electron microscopy, but in transmission electron microscopes (TEM), the optics is not in a 4f configuration. Instead, you have the objective lens, which produces a first intermediate image with a given magnification. The objective lens is followed by an intermediate lens, which images the intermediate image onto the detector with a given magnification. The total magnification is given by the product of the individual magnification of each lens. For a single lens, you need to look at the thin lens and magnification formulas (Eq. 24.3.1 and 24.3.1 in the Lenses Physics LibreTexts). I am copying both formulas below for reference.
Thin lens formula:

Magnification formula:

d are distances where o and i subscripts are object and image respectively, and f is the focal length. Assume a 1-mm focal length lens, and 1000 X magnification. This is possible with the object distance: 1.000999999999945mm and the image distance: 1001.000000000103mm. Note that the minus sign only produces an inverted image and doesn't change the absolute magnification (and it even cancels out in the calculation of the total magnification). If you combine two of those lenses, you get your 1 000 000X magnification with a total system length of about 2m. For the few TEM that I've seen in real life, this is comparable to height that these systems had. And for those system, it makes sense because the resolution is so much better thanks to the short wavelength of the electrons, as you mentioned. Once again, I'm not an expert in electron microscopy but I hope this makes sense.

Nice answer ;-)

So, resolution and magnification aren't depended variables, right?

It is true that the magnification does not appear in the calculation of the diffraction limit. However, the resolution is not always limited by diffraction. If the pixels with which you sample your image are too big they will limit the resolution and their size depends on the magnification. If the pixel is 4.5um and the magnification is 2X, the apparent pixel size is 2.25um. In this instance, the system cannot resolve more than twice the pixel size (sampling theorem) or 4.5um. Since the apparent pixel size depends on the magnification, the resolution depends on the magnification as well here.
